# HMAC sha1 signature mismatch with x-hub-signature headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to verify the HMAC signature but I tried almost everything but could not make it work. Below is my code..

```
const sig = request.headers['x-hub-signature'] || '';
            const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', '56e2a9fa00996dd4b026b55a5134df650acb42c83767dd5456eb2f3496ef85a4');
            const digest = Buffer.from('sha1=' + hmac.update(JSON.stringify(request.body)).digest('hex'), 'utf8');
            const checksum = Buffer.from(sig, 'utf8');
            if (checksum.length !== digest.length || !crypto.timingSafeEqual(digest, checksum)) {
                return console.log(`Request body digest (${digest}) did not match X-Hub-Signature (${checksum})`);
            }
```

Even the **content type is application/json**.. So please can anybody help me out in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer..
needed base64 and not the hex conversion :)